# Why is my code combining instead of adding numbers?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure why this is happening but when I run this it takes the numbers and combines them rather than adding them.

For example, if I type 1, 2, and 3 for each of the inputs, it will output $123 instead of $6.

This program calculates how much a garden center needs to spend for a flower garden display.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    // Get the cost of soil.
    std::string Soil;
    std::cout << "What does the soil cost? " <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> Soil;

    // Get the cost of flower seeds.
    std::string Flower;
    std::cout << "What do the flower seeds cost? " <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> Flower;

    // Get the cost of the fence.
    std::string Fence;
    std::cout << "What does the fence cost? " <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> Fence;

    // Calculate the total cost.
    std::string total;
    std::cout total = Soil + Flower + Fence;

    // Display the total cost
    std::cout << "The total cost is $" << total;
    std::cout << "." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is because `Soil`, `Flower` and  `Fence` are all strings. Surprisingly there is `operator +` for strings as well as for numbers. It will return a new string by concatenating operands. Also `std::cout total ` does not seem to be valid at all because `std::cout` and `total` are both variable names.

Comment: How do you add "hi", "I'm", "thebluefish" together? They aren't numbers, they're **strings**. What you're trying to combine are text strings, and so concatenation is a natural result. You might instead look for a way to convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use int instead of string.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
int soil, flower, fence, total;

// Get the cost of soil.
std::cout << "What does the soil cost? " <<std::endl;
std::cin >> soil;

// Get the cost of flower seeds.
std::cout << "What do the flower seeds cost? " <<std::endl;
std::cin >> flower;

// Get the cost of the fence.
std::cout << "What does the fence cost? " <<std::endl;
std::cin >> fence;

// Calculate the total cost.
total = Soil + Flower + Fence;

// Display the total cost
std::cout << "The total cost is $" << total;
std::cout << "." << std::endl;

return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You use data type string, and operator `+` for strings does string concatenation. For arithmetic calculations, use a numeric data type, e.g. `double`:

```
int main()
{
    // Get the cost of soil.
    double Soil;
    std::cout << "What does the soil cost? " <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> Soil;

    // Get the cost of flower seeds.
    double Flower;
    std::cout << "What do the flower seeds cost? " <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> Flower;

    // Get the cost of the fence.
    double Fence;
    std::cout << "What does the fence cost? " <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> Fence;

    // Calculate the total cost.
    double total =Soil + Flower + Fence;

    // Display the total cost
    std::cout << "The total cost is $" << total;
    std::cout << "." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your three variables are typed `string`, and `+` is the concatenation operator for strings.

Replace `std::string Soil;` with `int Soil;` and the same with `Flower` and `Fence` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, look at types you're using:

```
std::string Soil;
[...]
std::string Flower;
[...]
std::string Fence;
```

You're using text types instead of numbers, and standard sum operator `+` is by default overloaded to concatenate strings. Just change them to `int` or try converting.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is my code combining instead of of adding numbers?

Strings concatenate.

---

Another c++ approach to consider.

using std::stoi() to convert strings to int and provided in header < string >

```
int main(int, char**)
{
   // Get the cost of soil.
   std::string Soil;
   std::cout << "What does the soil cost? " <<std::endl;
   std::cin >> Soil;

   // Get the cost of flower seeds.
   std::string Flower;
   std::cout << "What do the flower seeds cost? " <<std::endl;
   std::cin >> Flower;

   // Get the cost of the fence.
   std::string Fence;
   std::cout << "What does the fence cost? " <<std::endl;
   std::cin >> Fence;

   // Calculate the total cost.
   int  total = (std::stoi(Soil) +
                 std::stoi(Flower) +
                 std::stoi(Fence));

   // Display the total cost
   std::cout << "The total cost is $"
             << total
             << "." << std::endl;

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: You need to evaluate how stoi handles the mistake when you typo an invalid decimal input,  For formatted input, you need to evaluate how the stream handles invalid decimal input.  IMHO - I think the stream formatted input is somewhat easier to recover, if that is what you want.  This means that your solution is not yet complete.

Answer (score -2):

C++ is type safe, meaning that when you declared Soil, Flower and Fence as type string, the standard input had to save them as strings. Therefore, the "+" is interpreted as concatenation, not addition.

I would either declare them as integer or unsigned integer and the same with total.

Or you could cast the values as integers or unsigned integers. I am too many years away from C and C++ to get syntax.

I think it might be:

```
std::string total = NumberToString((int)Soil + (int)Flower + (int)Fence);
```

Comment: `(int)Soil` tells the compiler to treat the `string` variable as an `int`.  There is no trivial conversion between `string` and `int` because most `string`s can't convert to `int`. Frankly I don't know what you will get from this, but it won't be pretty. Look into `std::stoi` for a function that will convert a `string` into an `int`.